# How to post on Facebook page with media content using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I'm trying to make an auto post to my Facebook page from my server, I'm using Nodejs and Facebook-node-sdk.

My problem is that i'm not able to add an image and I don't know how to upload a video using this package.

this is my code to post on my page text with Image (from URL) but this is not working I have only message appearing on my page.

```
var FB = require('fb');
var request = require('request');
FB.setAccessToken('MY_PAGE_TOKEN');

var body = 'My first post using facebook-sdk';
FB.api('me/feed/', 'post', { message: body ,url : 'http://google.com/doodle.png'}, function (res) {
  if(!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Post Id: ' + res.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used a year ago to upload a video in Node Js using Facebook Graph API:

```
// It publishes the video in chunks to Facebook until it finishes
var publishVideo = function(access_token, text, file) {

  var stats = fs.statSync(file.path);

  var formData = {
    access_token: access_token,
    upload_phase: 'start',
    file_size: stats.size
  };

  // First step, we send the video size
  request.post({ url: 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/me/videos', form: formData, json: true },
  function(err, response, body) {
    if (!err) {
      // With the response, we start making the video transfer
      transferProcess(undefined, file, access_token, body, function(err, currentUploadSession) {
        if (!err) {

          var formData = {
            access_token: access_token,
            upload_phase: 'finish',
            upload_session_id: currentUploadSession,
            description: text
          };

          // Once the video transfer ended, we publish the video
          request.post({ url: 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/me/videos', form: formData, json: true });
        }
      });
    }
  });
};

// It processes each part of the video until it finishes
var transferProcess = function(uploadSession, file, access_token, body, callback) {

  // First we generate a copy of the file in order to be independent to the original file
  // because it can have problems when opening it at the same time from other file
  var copyFileName = file.path + '-facebook';
  fse.copySync(file.path, copyFileName);

  // Once we have the copy, we open it
  var fd = fs.openSync(copyFileName, 'r');

  var bytesRead, data, bufferLength = 1000000000;
  var buffer = new Buffer(bufferLength);

  var length = body.end_offset - body.start_offset;

  // We read the amount of bytes specified from body.start_offset until length
  bytesRead = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, body.start_offset, length, null);
  data = bytesRead < bufferLength ? buffer.slice(0, bytesRead) : buffer;

  // We generate a file with the recently read data, and with a name of copyFileName-chunked-12313123
  var chunkFileName = copyFileName + '-chunked-' + body.start_offset;

  // We create the file so then we can read it and send it
  fs.writeFile(chunkFileName, data, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
    else {

      var currentUploadSession = uploadSession ? uploadSession : body.upload_session_id;
      var startOffset = parseInt(body.start_offset);

      var formData = {
        upload_phase: 'transfer',
        start_offset: startOffset,
        upload_session_id: currentUploadSession,
        access_token: access_token
      };

      formData.video_file_chunk = fs.createReadStream(chunkFileName);

      // Once we have the file written, we upload it
      request.post({ url: 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/me/videos',
      formData: formData, json: true }, function (err, response, body) {
        // If there was an error, we return it
        if (err || body.error) {
          callback(err ? err : body.error, null);
        }
        // If the lecture of the file has ended, facebook will send us the body.start_offset and the body.end_offset,
        // if they are the same, it means that we have ended uploading the video, so we return
        else if (body.start_offset === body.end_offset) {
          callback(err, currentUploadSession);
        }
        // Else, we keep reading the file
        else {
          transferProcess(currentUploadSession, file, access_token, body, callback);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Hope you can use it.

Joel

Answer (score 0):

To upload a photo you need to post to the /photos endpoint, not the /feed endpoint.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

```
FB.api('me/photos/', 'post', { caption: 'Photo description' ,url : 'http://google.com/doodle.png'}, function (res) {
  if(!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Post Id: ' + res.id);
});
```